# convert csv (;) deliminated file to Json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, data-conversion

I try to convert CSV file(; delimited) to JSON file 
and my CSV file structure is like below sample:
ID;NAME;AGE;CLASS;SEC 
1;ram;13;8;B

like that

```
import csv,json
csvf_path='xyz'
jsonf_path='mnb'
Data={}
with csv(csvf_path) as csvFile:
    csvRider=csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow as csvRider:
        ID=csvRow('ID')
        data[Id]=csvRow

with open(jsonf_path,'W') as jsonFile
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data,indent=4))
```

-->data[Id]=csvRow ---->error---->KEyerror 
i also try it using

```
csv.reader(csvf_path,delimiter=';')
```

then again I got an error,

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.
-->

```
ID=ID=csvRow('ID')
```

Answer (score 1):

The indentation in the provided code is wrong. Take a look at this part:

```
csvRider=csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow as csvRider:
    ID=csvRow('ID')
    data[Id]=csvRow
```

The `for` should be indented.

---

That said, use something like this to convert the CSV (`;`) into JSON

```py
import csv
import json

with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    rows = list(reader)

with open('result.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(rows, f)
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "NAME": "ram",
        "AGE": "13",
        "CLASS": "8",
        "SEC": "1"
    }
]
```

Comment: I corrected my python script .and sorry but this above mention script also not give me JSON file .please check your file with multiple data in CSV, I think you got your error.thanks for sharing a valuable comment on my Question.

Comment: HI. I've tested the code with a multi line CSV file, it works as expected. I've created a repl.it so you can test it yourself. Just press 'run' at the top of the page and you'll see the `result.json` appear in the filemanager on the left. [https://repl.it/repls/AbleForthrightPolygon](https://repl.it/repls/AbleForthrightPolygon)

Comment: sorry please check once [{"ID": "1", "NAME": "ram", "AGE": "13", "CLASS": "8", "SEC": "1"}, {"ID": "2", "NAME": "vram", "AGE": "5", "CLASS": "81", "SEC": "5"}]

Comment: i think we need to think on the solution once again

Comment: @Sudhakar Thats exactly what you asked for right? You can see the input file in the repl.it. Otherwise, please *edit* your question and add the desired output!